# Create Interactive UI in Unity

Tags: javascript, css, unity-game-engine, multi-touch, interactive

I have a requirement of creating an image gallery in unity (like flickr). Images will fill up the entire screen space and the user will be asked to select some of the images. After that the user will create on "Next" button and another set of images will replace the current set based on the selection.

I have an web application to do that but now I am instructed to build the same on unity. I know how to create custom UI elements using Javascript and CSS, like creating a rounded cornered div and a custom draggable slider control etc. I want to know how to do those in unity. Can I run CSS in unity for styling components?

I know unity is a game engine but it seems that I can make 2D interactive multi touch enabled user interface in unity. But I did not like the default GUI skin of unity.

Do I need to draw my components in Photoshop or GIMP or similar and import them or I can create them in unity itself?

Can anybody help with some starters please?

Answer (score 1):

You should read the documentation about GUISkin from Unity itself, maybe it's what you're looking for.

[Unity GUISkin](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GUISkin.html)

You can change every element in every state, pretty much like you do with CSS:

[image: GUISkin]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NGUI](http://cgcookie.com/unity/cgc-courses/getting-started-with-ngui-for-unity/), it is great open source tool for enhancing your game UI like this you can put sliders and other stuff too give it a try and tell.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Unity.com and download the last version. It's free.
2. Install it on your computer.
3. Make sure to open the last version of Unity, that ou have just installed.
4. Create a new project and save it.
5. In hierarchy press the right side of the mouse (right-click) and you shoul see many categories.
6. Select UI and, then, select the UI object that you want to create.
   Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely stay away from Unity GUISkin or NGUI. Use new Unity UI system. Its simple to use and faster than NGUI.

Here is a quick link to official tutorial how to use Image component. I recommend to go through them all
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-image